# How to get mysqli_connect to work?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to use mysqli_connect as such:

```
$host = "ftp.tatiana-renae.com";
$user = "tatiana";
$password = "********";
$dbname = "********";
$connection = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $dbname);
```

but I get this error:

Database connection failed: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'ftp.tatiana-renae.com' (111) (2003)

I know mysqli_connect works differently than mysql_connect but I can't figure out what to do for mysqli_connect to make it happy.  Any ideas?

Comment: MySQL doesn't run off an ftp server.

Comment: Second person in 24 hours to try to connect to an FTP server for MySQL.  Where is this coming from?

Comment: A great big fat **FIIK** there @Devon

Comment: @Fred-ii- my www.something.com servers run mysql, and ftp, and sftp, and ... and ... and many other services, especially my dev boxes. Dont be so literal with a stupid DNS name, it translates to an IP addy that belongs to a box, that can run many things.

Comment: well then, it surely must work for them too @YvesLeBorg my mistake.

Comment: How do I figure out what the host is?  I tried just using tatiana-renae.com

Comment: @devon .... that requires special DNS handling for primary domain names, if i recall. Much easier with most domain name vendors to assign subdomains and have them routed properly. I have boxes with multiple subdomains too like www. and ftp. and dev. and sandbox. all pointing to one machine. Gives flexibility.

Comment: Well for most web hosts, 127.0.0.1 works fine...  if mysql is hosted on the same server

Comment: I just tried $host = "127.0.0.1"; but I get the same error.

Comment: well not exactly the same obviously...
Database connection failed: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (13) (2003)

Comment: @Tanya well then, your web host should provide you with mysql details.  You'll need to consult their resources/manuals.

Comment: @Tanya : try to print/echo the $php_errormsg variable immediately after the connect error, you might get a hint. Also, importantly, is your php running in same box as the said machine ?

Answer (score 0):

Error 111 is "connection refused". One candidate explanation is that MySQL is not "listening" on the network, but only the TCP loopback address.

Check the my.cnf for the server, and check if it contains lines like this:

```
skip-networking
```

or

```
bind_address=127.0.0.1
```

If your PHP is running on the same server as MySQL, you can try using `'127.0.0.1'` for the host, in place of `'ftp.tatiana-renae.com'`.

Is the MySQL server running? Can you connect to it using the mysql command line interface?

There's several other possibilities; but there's not enough information provided about you environment for us to accurately diagnose the problem. We're just guessing.